# Refactor the first iteration for generator in python

Tags: python, loops, refactoring

I was wondering that whether there's a way to refactor the following codes

```
 first_run = True
 for i in gen:
        if first_run:
            last_head = i[1]
            last_tail = i[2]
            last_chrom = i[0]
            first_run = False
        else:
            func(i[1], last_head)
            func(i[1], last_tail)
            last_head = i[1]
            last_tail = i[2]
            last_chrom = i[0]
```

Comment: What's your concern with the current code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The essential point of your loop seems to be performing some operation on pairs of consecutive elements of the iterable. So I would look to the function `pairwise` whose definition is given in the [`itertools` module documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes):

```
def pairwise(iterable):
    "s -> (s0,s1), (s1,s2), (s2, s3), ..."
    a, b = tee(iterable)
    next(b, None)
    return izip(a, b)
```

Note that this is not an actual `itertools` function, you will have to copy and paste the implementation into your code. Anyway, with this function, your loop can be implemented like so:

```
for a, b in pairwise(gen):
    func(b[1], a[1])
    func(b[1], a[2])
```

Comment: Interesting, but I really don't want to maintain codes like this written by others..

Comment: Well... this is the way people write code in Python, so if you're learning the language, you'll see things like this a lot.

Answer (score 1):

this should simplify the loop

```
first_run = True
for i in gen:
    if first_run == False:
        func(i[1], last_head)
        func(i[1], last_tail)

     last_head, last_tail, last_chrom  = i[1], i[2], i[0]
     first_run = False
```

updated the answer...

Comment: For a large number of iterations, this **if** is rather inefficient

Comment: The title of the question says it's a generator, perhaps not entirely clearly though.

Comment: `next()` will pull the first item out, the for loop won't get it.

Answer (score 1):

I would remove **if**/ **else** and assign by slicing list - unless arguments of **func** are objects that are updated by it:
If gen is generator:

```
my_gen = gen
values = my_gen.next()
last_chrom, last_head, last_tail = values[:3]
for values in my_gen:
    func(last_head, last_head)
    func(last_head, last_tail)
    last_chrom, last_head, last_tail = values[:3]
```

EDIT:
Just noticed my mistake

Answer (score 0):

If your don't need the variables last_head, last_tail and last_chrom after the loop, you could take this solution:

```
for index, val in enumerate(gen[:1]):
    func(val[1], gen[index-1][1])
    func(val[1], gen[index-1][2])
```

Comment: `gen` is supposed to be a genarator, this only works with a list.

Answer (score 0):

```
it = iter(gen) # make sure we have an iterator
_, last_head, last_tail = next(it, [None]*3) # assume iterator returns 3 values
for _, head, tail in it:
    func(head, last_head)
    func(head, last_tail)
    last_head, last_tail = head, tail
```

If you can't assume that the iterator returns 3 values at a time then:

```
it = iter(gen)
last = next(it, None)
for x in it:
    func(x[1], last[1]) # head, last_head
    func(x[1], last[2]) # head, last_tail
    last = x
```

You could also use [`itertools`' `pairwise()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#recipes) recipe suggested by [@David](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13135251/4279):

```
for last, x in pairwise(gen):
    func(x[1], last[1]) # head, last_head
    func(x[1], last[2]) # head, last_tail
```

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way to process the "first item" in a special way is an one-time loop with `break`:

```
def gen():
    for x in range(5):
        yield x

def first_special(g):
    for item in g:
        print 'first', item
        break
    for item in g:
        print item

 first_special(gen())
 # prints "first 0, 1,2,3,4
```

Note that this works fine with one-element or empty iterators. To make `first_special` work with arbitrary iterables as well, I usually add a safety `iter()` call to it:

```
def first_special(g):
    g = iter(g)
    for item in g:
        print 'first', item
        break
    for item in g:
        print item
```